# worth to drive? worth the drive? worth it the drive?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

Me and my friend(american) went to the ice-cream shop and It took us 30 mins of drive. I thought It was too far but my friend kept telling me it is far but totally worth it. After arriving, we ordered and I had to admit that it was good. I told him "It is worth driving here.". But he corrected my grammar there saying "It's worth to drive.". So I googled it, but none of them say "worth to drive" since "be worth" is must go with gerund after that. Who's correct? and also, Can I say "It's worth it 30 mins drive."?

Comment: *It is worth driving here* is fine, although it would probably be said as *It's worth driving here*, unless you wanted to put it in the past tense, since you have already arrived and ordered. Also, *It took us 30 minutes to drive* is natural, not *30 minutes of drive*.

Comment: _Worth_ takes a noun phrase complement, which may be a gerund, but not an infinitive. So both _worth a drive_ and _worth driving_ are OK, but not *_worth to drive_. _Worth it_, with _it_ object, is an idiom and **can** take an infinitive -- _It's worth it to drive there_ is OK and means the same as _It's worth driving there_. More details on _worth, value, price,_ and _cost_ [available here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: I suspect you misheard your friend. That aside, there is a new intransitive slang use of *worth* these days.

Comment: Thank you all. I think I misheard,too. Anyways now I understood clearly :)

Answer (score 4):

The idiom is

> It's worth the *(name your inconvenience)*.
>
> It's worth the drive.
>   It's worth the walk.
>   It's worth the wait.
>   It's worth the weight *(eating this muffin)*  - *this is an intended pun*

meaning, although not easy to attain, the result is gratifying.

You might also say

> The drive, was it worth it?
>   Was it worth it, the drive?

although the latter sentence may get parsed as "Was it worth it? The drive?"

In your final example

> It's worth **the** 30mins drive.
>   It's worth **it, the** 30mins drive.

Answer (score 2):

"Worth the drive" is a grammatically correct way of saying it, and the one I hear the most. I must admit I have never heard "worth to drive" and that it sounds odd to me.

"Worth driving here" also works for me.

I'd say that it comes from my expectation that "it is worth [something]" must be a noun (or a gerund, which acts as a noun) to work.